# CSS selector for first child component of another Angular component

Tags: angular, css-selectors

In Angular, I need to select the first child component of a parent component with some CSS (SASS) rules. I have a list of items that is one component, and then I have the list items, which are components themselves. So it is structured like:

```
<product-list>
    <list-item />
    <list-item />
    <list-item />
</product-list>
```

The CSS rules for each component are isolated to only that component, so I am not able to use the first-child selector to select the first list-item.

Spoken differently, since the rules in the product-list SASS file do not apply to its children, and the rules in the list-item SASS file do not apply to their parents, I cannot use product-list:first-child in either of the two SASS files, because either file needs to reference both the list parent, and list child.

For one, I would like to know what this CSS rule isolation is called. It's a nice feature, but it's blocking me here.

I could write the rule in the global SASS, but that doesn't seem like it would be the best way.

Can someone show me the true Angular way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a piercing css combinator. The "isolation" is called "encapsulation".

Answer (score 0):

There your go https://plnkr.co/edit/FPqx6m12tkmMFlf5LvJl?p=preview

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-li",
    styles:[`
     :host {
         color:blue

     }

    `]
    template: `
        <li>This is my li</li>
    `
})
export class MyLi {

}


@Component({
    selector: "navbar",
    directives: [NgFor,MyLi], 
    styles: [`
        my-li:nth-child(2){
          color: yellow;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <h2>Democratic Party presidential candidates</h2>
        <ul>
          <my-li *ngFor="#item of items; #i = index">{{item}} {{i}}</my-li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class Navbar {
    items: Array<String>

    constructor() {
      this.items = [
        "Hillary Clinton",
        "Martin O'Malley",
        "Bernie Sanders"
      ]
    }

}
```

NOTE : This is using an old version of Angular2 , in the new version there is no directives array in the **@component** , so don't get confused , just look at the styles.

Comment: It took me some time to understand but now I get it: the `:host` selector is the key here. Thanks!